# Is there an alternative to overloading or template specialization? I am attempting to call a specific function based on a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++20

I have generated a simpler example of what I am trying to accomplish.  I would like to be able to call a function, which returns a class containing two template parameters, based on one of the two templated parameters (Variance).

My hierarchy can be simplified to this.

```
template<typename T>
class AbstractType {};

template<typename T, Variance Type>
class BaseType : public AbstractType<T> {};

template<typename T, Variance Type>
class FinalType : public BaseType<T, Type>{};
```

Where FinalType in this example isn't strictly necessary, it also inherits from other templated classes in my actual code, which serves no purpose in this example, so it's been removed.

Here's the example code.

```
enum class Variance {
    Interval,
    Weighted,
    Constant
};

template<typename T>
class AbstractType
{
protected:
    AbstractType(T* _Instance) :
        Instance(_Instance) {};

    T* Instance;
};

template<typename T, Variance Type>
class BaseType : public AbstractType<T>
{
protected:
    BaseType(T* _Instance) :
        AbstractType<T>(_Instance) {};
};

template<typename T>
class BaseType<T, Variance::Interval> : public AbstractType<T>
{
protected:
    BaseType(T* _Instance) :
        AbstractType<T>(_Instance) {};

    int Interval;
public:
    void SetInterval(int NewInterval) { Interval = NewInterval; }
};

template<typename T>
class BaseType<T, Variance::Weighted> : public AbstractType<T>
{

protected:
    BaseType(T* _Instance) :
        AbstractType<T>(_Instance) {};

    int Weight;
public:
    void SetWeight(int NewWeight) { Weight = NewWeight; }
};

template<typename T, Variance Type>
class FinalType : public BaseType<T, Type>
{
public:
    FinalType(T* _Instance) :
        BaseType<T, Type>(_Instance) 
    {};
};

struct Interface
{

    template<typename T>
    BaseType<T, Variance::Weighted>* CreateBaseInstance(T t, int Weight) {
        FinalType<T, Variance::Weighted>* OutObj = new FinalType<T, Variance::Weighted>(t);
        OutObj.SetWeight(Weight);
        return OutObj;
    }

    template<typename T>
    BaseType <T, Variance::Interval>* CreateBaseInstance(T t, int Interval) {
        FinalType<T, Variance::Weighted>* OutObj = new FinalType<T, Variance::Interval>(t);
        OutObj.SetInterval(20);
        return OutObj;
    }
};


struct Object {};
void test()
{
    Interface Inter;

    Object Obj;
    Inter.CreateBaseInstance<Object, Variance::Weighted>(Obj, 50);  // Too many template arguments
    Inter.CreateBaseInstance<Object, Variance::Interval>(Obj, 10);  // Too many template arguments

    Inter.CreateBaseInstance<Object>(Obj, 50);  // More than one instance of overloaded function
    Inter.CreateBaseInstance<Object>(Obj, 10);  // More than one instance of overloaded function
}
```

Additionally, Object being used as the first template is just for testing purposes.  I will not know the type in this codebase.

I've been able to resolve this problem by creating multiple functions such as..

```
template<typename T>
BaseType<T, Variance::Interval>* CreateIntervalInstance(T t, int Interval)…

template<typename T>
BaseType<T, Variance::Weighted>* CreateWeightedInstance(T t, int Weight)…

template<typename T>
BaseType<T, Variance::Constant>* CreateConstantInstance(T t)…
```

However, as mentioned earlier, FinalType inherits from another set of classes, so while the above works, it becomes crowded and unsustainable with the number of functions needed to do the simple tasks above.

I have experimented with making the Interface have a template parameter, such as..

```
// Base Class
template<Variance Variant>
class Interface…

// Specialized
template<>
class Interface<Variance::Interval>…
// Functions to create Interval Instances

//Specialized
template<>
class Interface<Variance::Weighted>…
// Functions to create Weighted Instances
```

But, I once again run into it becoming unsustainable.

The last thing I am currently looking into is Type Traits, but am unsure if or how that could be implemented to make this simpler.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (like `_Instance`) are reserved in _all contexts_. You are not allowed to use them as name in any declaration or macro definition. Doing so causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without following all of it really in detail, don't you just want e.g.

```
template<typename T, Variance Type>
auto CreateBaseInstance(T t, int value) {
    // Instead of `auto` maybe `std::unique_ptr<BaseType<T, Type>>`
    auto OutObj = std::make_unique<FinalType<T, Type>>(t);
    
    if constexpr(Type == Variance::Weighted) {
        OutObj->SetWeight(value);
    } else if constexpr(Type == Variance::Interval) {
        OutObj->SetInterval(value);
    }
    
    return OutObj;
}
```

(I replaced `new` with `std::make_unique`, because using raw `new` like this is generally considered bad practice due to the memory management problems it causes.)

Comment: This solved my problem as well as a handful of others.  Is it possible for "value" to be updated to either "Weight" or "Interval", depending on Type? 
Specifically when calling the function with it showing the a parameter type and name.

Comment: @Atijaf No, the name of the parameter has no meaning outside the definition, but you can't have multiple names depending on the specialization. But the name has no meaning anyway except for documentation which you can just add out-of-line.

Comment: That's understandable.  I have one other consequence resulting from the solution above.  I have an additional Variant type called Constant, which does not need "Value".  I'd like to remove the parameter Value in the case that Variance == Constant.  Is this possible?

- I've managed to make it work by using std::enable_if<Variant != Variance::Constant...> along with it's opposite tied to two functions, but this seems messy and unintuitive.

Comment: @Atijaf Since you are using C++20 you can simplify that by writing `requires (Variant != Variance::Constant)` under the head of the function before the `{` or under the template head after the `>` (and equivalently on the other overload).